# How to through PPTP?

Tags: networking, nat, pptp

Basically I have a PPTP server, and there are pptp end-point and a real network "behind" it with servers and I want to test the bandwidth from a server which is on the real network to the clients which connect over PPTP, so how does the server connect to the pptp client with virtual ip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PPTP server should proxy arp the addresses of the clients connected to it. Your network must be configured to route these subnets to the appropriate devices or connectivity will fail. There really isn't much to this and your question is a little vague.

Comment: my purpose is to test the bandwidth from the real network to pptp client .

Comment: so i need to make the real network can connect the pptp clinet first

Comment: I believe I've already answered the question, the remote client will receive an address issued from the PPTP server. Depending on your implementation this will either be an internal IP or it could be a separate routed network. A diagram might be useful.